# ffmpeg cmd migration kubuntu14 to Win7

Tags: windows-7, ffmpeg

I have a ffmpeg cmd line that works fine in Kubuntu14 linux that I want to migrate to Win7.

```
ffmpeg -r 8 -threads 0 -f image2 -i './Pictures/AS_p20_RS6wvlt_png/Jupiter_20150327_%2d.png' -codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 16 -r 24 -y ./Video/Jupiter_20150327_win7.mp4
```

Turns out it stubbornly gives an error falsely claiming that the files are not there. I've tried messing with the '/' into '\' (I though MSFT likes that better, but no avail.)

Any help to get this run at Win7 is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Gert

[Screen shot for illustration](http://drgert.dyndns.ws:8000/download/win7_ffmpeg_01.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried without the quotes?

Comment: @slhck : No effect.